# I am using a List which contains items, in the view but it throws conversion error, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am using .net core with EF and Razor pages.

```
 List<BloodGroups> ListBloodGroups;
        public void OnGet()
        {
            BloodGroupsModel.ListBloodGroups = _donorsDBContext.GetBloodGroups();


        }
```

bloodgroups.cs

```
    public class BloodGroups
    {
        public BloodGroups() 
        {

        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BloodGroupID { get; set; }
        public string BloodGroupName { get; set; }
        
        public List<BloodGroups> ListBloodGroups { get; set; }         

       

    }
```

in view

```
 <select asp-for="BloodGroupsModel.BloodGroupID" asp-items="Model.BloodGroupsModel.ListBloodGroups"></select>
```

but error is

Cannot convert generic list to IEnumerable.

I a bit new to this and tried but it's not working I think it should have worked because technically I am calling methods based on model.

In DonorsDBContext class

```
   public List<BloodGroups> GetBloodGroups()
        {

            var list = new List<BloodGroups>();

            list = this.BloodGroups.ToList();

            return list;
        }
```

Comment: The `asp-items` property expects a collection of type `SelectListItem`, as explained [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists#razor-select-lists) and less direct in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper). In your example a collection of type `BloodGroup` is bound, which is not convertible to `SelectListItem`.

Comment: This post needs details or clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
<select asp-for="BloodGroupsModel.BloodGroupID" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.BloodGroupsModel.ListBloodGroups,"BloodGroupID","BloodGroupName"))"></select>
```

Be sure `ListBloodGroups` in your backend contains data.

My testing data in backend:

```
public BloodGroups BloodGroupsModel { get; set; }
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    BloodGroupsModel = new BloodGroups();
    BloodGroupsModel.ListBloodGroups = new List<BloodGroups>()
    {
        new BloodGroups(){BloodGroupID=1,BloodGroupName="aaa"},
        new BloodGroups(){BloodGroupID=2,BloodGroupName="bbb"},
        new BloodGroups(){BloodGroupID=3,BloodGroupName="ccc"}
    };
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetBloodGroups()
 {
       return  _donorsDBContext.Select( i=> new SelectListItem
         {
         Value = i.BloodGroupID.ToString(),
         Text = i.BloodGroupName 
         }).ToList();
}
```

and change your BloodGroups:

```
public List<SelectListItem> ListBloodGroups {get; set;}
```